# SSRS subscription fails when there is an email in the CC field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

This is absolutely baffling.

I have quite a few SSRS subscriptions, and suddenly within the last week, any of them that had an email in the CC of the subscription settings has failed. If I remove the CC, they work.

The error in the log seems to bear no relevance to the actual issue:

```
ERROR: Exception caught instantiating TERADATA report server extension: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Teradata.Client.Provider, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=76b417ee2e04956c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
ERROR: Exception caught instantiating ORACLE report server extension: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
ERROR: Exception caught instantiating SQLPDW report server extension: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

I've searched, but haven't found anyone else with this issue.
I've tried restarting the SSRS service, but no joy.

Really odd. Any ideas most welcome.
SSRS version is Enterprise 2017 (14.0.600.1274) and SQL Server that the report server database is on is 2019.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I filled DateTime report parameter from a data-driven DataSet. While filled in by constant the problem disappeared. Probably something with formating?

Unfortunatelly a solution was not found, I reworked the subscription to use defaults embedded within the report itself.